# How to edit TcxGrid properties by code in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

**What the program does** 
I have a function that dynamically generates a table and populates it. So...
**What's the problem?**
The problem is that i've tried looking for a way to edit a specific column properties by code since I can't (Obviously) use the normal properties Editor in delphi, but I've haven't had any success so far.

Here's what I've tried SO far:

```
for I := GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.ColumnCount - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.Columns[I].Destroy;
end;
GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.DataController.CreateAllItems;

GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.Columns[0].PropertiesClassName := 'CheckBox';
```

It doesn't show the CheckBox, I know it shouldn't do anything since i didn't set the checked status and neither how to recognize the String to set it as checked or not checked. But i expected at least to see the checkBox.

Comment: FWIW: I always use `PropertiesClass` instead of `PropertiesClassName`, i.e.`GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.Columns[0].PropertiesClass := TcxCheckBoxProperties;`.

Comment: Setting `DataBinding.ValueTypeClass` to `TcxBooleanValueType` might help, too.

Comment: I'll try!! Thank you very Much!

Comment: Hey @UliGerhardt, It worked as you said in the first comment. There is a problem with the second one tho. Since the program is not mine and neither is the Database where i get the data from i can't change the value type because it would mess with othe parts of the software. Is there a way to change, by code, the property "ValueChecked" and "ValueUnchecked"?

Comment: Something like `TcxCheckBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).ValueChecked := bla` should work.

Comment: I changed the title to remove XE10 since there's no such thing. Also, a websearch leads to plenty of info on the devexpress site. Did you check there?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know if it's just me, but on those websites' documentation i can't find a clear explenation of what functions do or what functions to use. I've tried even for other things (Like cell color depending on other columns Content) but i couldn't find nothing clear, just some function where they say type of parameters and function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the wrong classname, passing `'TcxCheckBoxProperties'` will work:

```
GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.Columns[0].PropertiesClassName := 'TcxCheckBoxProperties';
```

Anyhow, I always prefer to set the `PropertiesClass` property, instead of the `PropertiesClassName` property:

```
uses
  cxCheckBox;

...

GridOrdiniMagazzinoPadreView1.Columns[0].PropertiesClass := TcxCheckBoxProperties;
```